# No map received | rvis | le potato aml-s905X-cc | rp lidar a1

Tags: ros2, slam, turtlebot3, rplidar, cartographer

I currently have a SLAMTEC RPlidar a1 hooked up to a le potato (rasp pi copy).

I'm trying to run turtlebot3 cartographer (and eventually nav2). When I run the command

`ros2 launch turtlebot3_cartographer cartographer.launch.py`

it launches rvis and shows the error "No TF data. Actual error:Frame [map] does not exist" to solve this we've ran

`ros2 run tf2_ros static_transformer_publisher 0 0 0 0 0 0 map laser`

After running this we "solve" our TF error and can set the Fixed frame to map and rvis is displaying the lidar data in real time. however we then get the error "no map received." And this is where we are stuck

I've ran `ros topic list` and `ros topic info /map --verbose` and both tell me that we are publishing a map topic that is sending an occupancy grid to rvis.

*Additional information:*

when running cartographer the terminal repeats the error `"imu_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exsist` is this something I should be concerned about, do I need to add an imu to my system?

We've also tried running `ros2 launch turtlebot3_cartographer occupancy_grid.launch.py` and that "runs" but freezes before it launches rvis the last command sent it `process started with pid[3058]`